# MIgration from SVN into Git

Tags: git, svn

We are currently using SVN as our version control, I was asked to evaluate git, I found it to be a great version control and would like to migrate one of our projects into it.
I searched the internet for migration tools, and was hoping to pick this community brain as to which tool is better.
the SVN check in history must be migrated as well, this is a must have feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [Github](https://github.com). It supports both Git and SVN. I believe this would be a good middleman for converting between the two. You could just push your SNV to github then clone back down with Git.

Comment: @NoahHuppert what about revision history?

Comment: I believe it saves it but you should check just in case. You can do this by creating a blank workspace that uses SNV. Then make a file and have some simple changes between commits. Then push to Github and then pull with git and see if it worked.